# How do you properly remove "REQUIRE SSL" from a single user?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, ssl, permissions

I successfully granted REQUIRE SSL to a single user by doing...

```
mysql -u"${targetMySqlUser}" -p"${targetMySqlPass}" -e "GRANT USAGE ON dbname.* TO 'dbusername'@'%' REQUIRE SSL;"
```

but im failing on REMOVING or REVOKING this flag from the user, using revoke. i guess im fighting with the syntax. Is there a proper way to remove it with the "revoke" command, without revoking the whole permission ?

MySQL 5.5 manual , this site and the interwebs didn't helped me yet finding a proper counter-way.

This SQL statement will work.

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET ssl_type = '' WHERE ssl_type = 'any' ; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

but I believe where is a `GRANT REQUIRE SSL` there must me a `REVOKE REQUIRE SSL`, isn't there ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you are looking for does not exist in MySQL 5.5

Unfortunately, the [ALTER USER command for MySQL 5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-user.html) is limited. All you can do is

```
ALTER USER user@host PASSWORD EXPIRE;
```

In MySQL 5.7, you could run the [ALTER USER command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-user.html) as follows

```
ALTER USER user@host REQUIRE NONE;
```

When it comes to MySQL 5.5, you did the most expedient way possible. Great !!!

A more politically correct way would have been to do the following:

```
DROP USER user@host;
CREATE USER user@host;
GRANT ... on ... TO user@host IDENTIFIED BY '...';
```

Otherwise, I commend you for doing what was needed.

Comment: Good answer for various MySQL versions. For MySQL 5.6, [@Abey's solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/182337/149697) does not require dropping and re-creating users.

Answer (score 8):

This was one of the google results when I wanted to remove `REQUIRE SSL` on a MySQL user that I  enforced. [What I did was do](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html) `REQUIRE NONE` on `USAGE`

```
GRANT USAGE ON dbname.* TO 'dbusername'@'%' REQUIRE NONE;
```

Verify if the settings have been changed by running

`SHOW GRANTS FOR 'dbusername'@'%' ;`

Worked on MySQL 5.6

Comment: Worked like a charm on MySQL 5.6. Elegant and simple :)

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? I'am using Mysql verison 5.7.22. SHOW GRANTs doesn't mention SSL - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56203365/how-to-check-if-a-user-requires-ssl-in-mysql

Comment: `ALTER USER` is probably best for newer versions of MySQL/MariaDB but `GRANT ... REQUIRE NONE` is required on older versions.